# Xamarin.forms Highlight URL from text

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, string-parsing

I have Xamarin.Forms app which identify URLs from label and provide click to the URL using span gestures and show in a `webview`.

The sample text which I bind to the label from API result is like this:

```
test
Test description
Test description2

Files :
https://notification-assets.com/1586370078029
https://notification-assets.com/1586370078037
https://notification-assets.com/1586370078063
```

How I am fetching URLs from this text:

The urlStr is my text conatins URLS

```
string[] words = urlStr.Split(' ').ToArray();
formattedString = new FormattedString();
foreach (string str in words)
{
    if (IsUrl(str))
    {
        Span span = new Span() { Text = str + " ", TextColor = Color.FromHex("#261fee"), TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Italic };
        span.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            Command = new Command(async () => {

                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new WebviewPopup(span.Text));
            })
        });
        formattedString.Spans.Add(span);
    }
    else
    {
        Span span = new Span() { Text = str + " ", TextColor = Color.Gray };
        formattedString.Spans.Add(span);
    }
}

private static bool IsUrl(string url)
{
    string pattern = @"((https?|ftp|file)\://|www.)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return reg.IsMatch(url);
}
```

This will highlight the three URLS, but in My `webview` I will get the URLS like this

```
":\nhttps://notification-assets.com/1586370078029\nhttps://notification-assets.com/1586370078037\nhttps://notification-assets.com/1586370078063\n "
```

First of all I don't want to get the 3 URLs even  if we are clicking one of the URLs.

Secondly how to remove the `/n` and `:` from the formatted URL? How to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should split with '\n' instead

Comment: Could you show your urlStr ? I test with the string `string urlStr = "https://notification-assets.com/1586370078029 https://notification-assets.com/1586370078037 https://notification-assets.com/1586370078063";` and it works well. You could make a break point on the line `PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new WebviewPopup(span.Text));`  to see if `span.Text`  is right or not .

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT. It worked when I split with '\n' as sueggested by shanranm

Comment: @shanranm could your comment  as an answer for future users ?